# Save files with mime type in c#

Tags: c#, io, mime-types

I want to save files in disk with their mime types instead of extension
becuase some users may send extenstion wrong and want to use the mime type the browser sends to my program.

how can I save files with mime in disk with c#

Comment: For the mime types that have a single extension associated with them you can change the extension to match your mime otherwise there is no way to do that because for a single mime type you might face different file types which should be known otherwise.

Comment: @Emad will you explain more with some examples?you mean that a mime type maybe use for multiple exetention? so if I want to use extension and mime type both, for writing file to disk, is there any solution?

Comment: Take `image/jpeg` for example. This might be a file with these formats: `jfif`, `jpe`, `jpeg` and `jps`. Basically MIME type is for a different use you can't use it as an analog to file type.

Comment: @Emad ok. so how can I use both of them in saving? I mean sometimes extention might be wrong. want to use both filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shall compose what I have said in the comments here as an answer for further use.
MIME Type or Internet Media Type is used in the internet where there are many resources exchanged between servers and clients and there is no file is involved. The browser or the client application receiving the resource should know what to do with it, is it an image to show or is it a javascript to run for example. This is done in the web using MIME types. The nature of the resource should be known by the server and MIME type is constructed in server with this knowledge of what the resource is.

For example if you request a URL `http://domain/resource1` the server knows the resource is a file **of type** jpeg and constructs the MIME type of `image/jpeg` for it.

Basically, file type is a bigger information than MIME type you can construct MIME from file type but not in reverse.

For more info on MIME Types see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type)
For a list of MIME Types see [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/)